# Using two type of ListView together

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to create a `ListView` using two libraries. The first one is a `SwipeMenuListView`

```
<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the second one is `PagedHeadListView`.

```
<com.jorgecastilloprz.pagedheadlistview.PagedHeadListView
    android:id="@+id/pagedHeadListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    pagedheadlistview:headerHeight="@dimen/header_height"
    pagedheadlistview:indicatorType="bottomAligned"
    pagedheadlistview:disableVerticalTouchOnHeader="true"
    pagedheadlistview:indicatorBgColor="@color/material_green"
    pagedheadlistview:indicatorColor="@color/material_light_green" />
```

As you can see that there are two different types of ListView

1. `<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView`
2. `<com.jorgecastilloprz.pagedheadlistview.PagedHeadListView`

My question is:

Is it possible to use both of them on the same `ListView`?
Maybe it's a stupid question but I haven't found anything about this.

Comment: You mean, can you somehow use both of them in one XML element, and have the resulting `ListView` have properties of both classes? No, you cannot. You might be able to combine both classes manually, but you'd have to do that at the source level.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Then is there any other way to do that? For example use one of them in XML element and somehow in java code add the other?

Comment: No, there's no simple way to do what you want (well, not _that_ simple). As mentioned, it might be possible to combine them both, but it would take modifying their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Every view element in XML maps directly to a Java class that knows how to display it and react to user input.  You can't have a single element map to two different classes-  which one would draw it?  Which one would respond to user input?  If you want a List that has a mix of those two behaviors you'll have to write a class that has a mix of those two behaviors.